# Работа статического метода при многопоточности

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Всем привет!

Начал изучать потоки. Автор курса, который я прохожу, привел пример работы с статическими методами при многопоточности. Он обратил внимание, что хотя статический метод обычно существует в единственном экземпляре (так как принадлежит всему объекту), при выполнении этого метода в двух потоках для каждого из них создается как бы копия метода; при этом автор отмечает, что слово «копия» используется для упрощенного понимания в данном учебном материале, после чего — цитирую:

> На самом деле происходят очень хитрые процессы — такие как с локальным хранилищем потока с сохранением промежуточных вычислений регистров — так как НА САМОМ ДЕЛЕ СТАТИЧЕСКИЙ МЕТОД ВСЕ РАВНО ОДИН. Но благодаря этим сложным процессам и механизмам у нас создается иллюзия того, что статический метод копируется. ... Но нам как высокоуровневым программистам это неинтересно.

Что это за механизмы? Как они используются для создания иллюзии копии статического метода? И при чем тут «хранилище потока с сохранением промежуточных вычислений регистров»? Что это за хранилище?

На другом форуме подметили, что автор имел в виду, что ни обычные методы классов, ни статические не копируются.

Возможно, имелся в виду стек, который системой создается для каждого потока; но и стек это не копирование. Тогда я не знаю, что имел ввиду автор курса — он говорил, что именно у статических методов имеются какие-то механизмы, которые и создают иллюзию их копирования.

Если автор всё же ошибался, порошу дать определение понятий из цитаты и разъяснить, что же хотел сказать автор. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: "они образованность показать хочут ..."  Зачем говорить, что метод копируется, если он не копируется? Все это можно объяснить, используя понятие "stack frame". Каждый косноязыкий думает, что может преподавать.

Comment: Ничего никуда не копируется. Нет никакой иллюзии копирования. Нет никакого хитрого механизма именно для статических методов. Просто каждый поток выполняет метод сам по себе, не оглядываясь на остальные потоки.

Comment: чего только не узнаешь в "этих ваших интернетах". Я вам больше скажу, то что написал в ответе VladD, относится ко всем методам и даже к свойствам (не путать с полями). Не статические тоже никуда не копируются, просто в отличие от статических вызвать их без указания конкретного объекта нельзя.

Comment: Также мне сказали, чтр данная тема касается вот этой статьи из Википедии:. Переключение контекста (англ. context switch) — в многозадачных ОС и средах - процесс прекращения выполнения процессором одной задачи (процесса, потока, нити) с сохранением всей необходимой информации и состояния, необходимых для последующего продолжения с прерванного места, и восстановления и загрузки состояния задачи, к выполнению которой переходит процессор.  - так ли это?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Думайте о методе так: метод — это инструкция по выполнению, типа кулинарного рецепта. То, что метод выполняется, означает, что поток читает инструкции и выполняет их.

Понятно, что ничего не мешает двум потокам одновременно делать это.

Comment: Также мне сказали, чтр данная тема касается вот этой статьи из Википедии:.   Переключение контекста (англ. context switch) — в многозадачных ОС и средах - процесс прекращения выполнения процессором одной задачи (процесса, потока, нити) с сохранением всей необходимой информации и состояния, необходимых для последующего продолжения с прерванного места, и восстановления и загрузки состояния задачи, к выполнению которой переходит процессор.

Comment: @BadCats: Переключение контекста — это то, как выполнение переходит от потока к потоку, нужно для случая, когда потоков больше, чем ядер у процессора (или всех процессоров системы, если их много). То есть практически всегда, т. к. обычно у вас есть сотни процессов, и у каждого по нескольку потоков.